# AVD Galaxy S6, huge icons and fonts issue

Tags: android-virtual-device

I am creating an AVD for a Galaxy S6.  I have downloaded the skin and followed the instructions at the Samsung Developer site:

developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

However, when I fire up my AVD, the fonts and icons are just massive and its unusable.  Please see the screenshots for my config and what it looks like.

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuzdu.png)

[How it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBwgd.png)

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Is there some settings with Resolution or Density that I need to change to get it to display properly?

I've tried a couple of things.

1. If I don't select the downloaded skin from the Skin dropdown (I just select ***Skin with dynamic hardware controls***) it displays a little bit better.  However for testing I want to nail the exact dimensions of the Galaxy S6.
2. I've tried selecting the ***Scale display to real size*** when I fire up the AVD but this only makes the actual AVD window smaller, does nothing to the actual Galaxy S6 screen size.

My machine is Windows 7, running on a 1920 x 1200 monitor.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the scale didn't show up on Android Studio for macOS, the solution for me  was

```
Tools > Android > AVD Manager

Samsung Galaxy S6 (AVD) > Edit Icon (Edit this AVD) > Show Advanced Settings > Device Frame > Uncheck: [] Enable Device Frame > Finish
```

reboot AVD and the scale on your Samsung Galaxy S6 should be normal.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, except my icons were even larger.  I found that setting the screen density for the device to ldpi or something lower than Samsung's recommendation of 560 dpi fixes the issue. I had to also edit the AVD after making the change to the device for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scale should help with the issue.

Under the menu: Tools > Android > AVD Manager

Find your device and click its edit icon.  If you change the scale and restart your emulator it should look much better. [Screenshot of Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGqQ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

All i did for mine to work, was to check the resolution of an image in the custom skin folder and use it as the resolution of the phone in my configuration on the android studio . That all !!!